How do you prove that compact operators on a Hilbert space are weak to weak continuous?
I'm actually trying to understand the proof for the statement that

Let $T \in K(H,H)$ for Hilbert space $H$, and $(x_n) \subset H, x_n
> \rightharpoonup 0$ weakly. Then $\|Tx_n\| \to 0$ strongly.

I found several proofs (e.g. here and this one and another one), however they all skip one part which is crucial for my understanding:
First they assume that $\|Tx_n\|$ does not converge to $0$, hence there is a subsequence $\|Tx_{n_j}\| > \varepsilon \quad (*)$. And now since $x_n \rightharpoonup 0$ weakly we have that $x_{n_j} \rightharpoonup 0$ weakly.
And thus $x_{n_j}$ bounded and $Tx_{n_j}$ must have a conv. subseq. since $T$ is compact. Now they argue that $Tx_{n_j}$ doesn't converge to zero due to $(*)$ but since $Tx_{n_j} \rightharpoonup 0$ that is a contradiction.
But how do we know that compact operators are weak to weak continuous?
I would have to show that if for $\forall L \in H': Lx_n \to 0 \implies \forall L \in H': LTx_n \to 0$ but $LT$ is not necessarily cont.?
I would be grateful for any hints.

Compact operators are bounded, and bounded operators are weak-to-weak continuous. In fact,

Theorem. For a linear operator $T \colon X \to Y$ between normed spaces, the following are equivalent:

$T$ is is bounded.
$T$ is weak-to-weak continuous, i.e., $T \colon (X,σ(X,X^*)) \to (Y,σ(Y,Y^*))$ is continuous.


This easily follows from the  universtality of the weak topology:
Lemma. A linear map $T \colon X \to Y$ is weak-to-weak continuous if and only if, for every $ y^* \in Y^* $, the linear functional   $  y^*  \circ T \colon X \to \mathbb R$ is bounded.
Proof. If $T$ is weak-to-weak continuous, then the composition $y^* \circ T$  is a weakly continuous functional, i.e. bounded, for every $y^* \in Y^*$. For the converse, it suffices to show that $T$ is continuous at the origin. Moreover, it suffices to show that, for every sub-basic weakly open subset $V$ of $Y$, its inverse image $T^{-1} [V]$ is open in $X$. Since each such  $V$ is of the form  $V=V_{y^*,ε}=  (y^*)^{-1}[(-ε,ε)]$ for $y^* \in Y^* $ and $\epsilon>0$, we have that
$$ T^{-1} [V] = (y^* \circ T)^{-1} [(-ε,ε)] $$
which is open in $X$ by the hypothesis.
To prove the Theorem, note that  if $T$ is bounded then each functional $y^* \circ T$ is bounded so by the Lemma we get that $(1) \implies (2)$. For the converse, consider the canonical isometric embedding   $  e : Y \to Y^{**} $. Then
$$ \langle e(Τx) , y^*\rangle  = \langle y^*,Tx\rangle  = \langle  y^* \circ T,  x\rangle , \quad  \forall y^* \in Y^*. $$
Since $T$ is weak-to-weak continuous, the above lemma implies that
$$
 \sup_{x \in B_X}  |  \langle e(Tx),y^* \rangle | \leq \|  y^* \circ T\| <+ \infty , \quad  \forall y^* \in Y^*.
 $$
The uniform boundedness principle implies that $\sup \{ ||e(Tx)|| \colon x \in B_X \}  < +\infty $ i.e. $\|T\|<\infty$.

Every bounded operator is weak to weak continuous. Indeed, $L$ is given by $\langle \xi, \cdot \rangle$ for some $\xi \in H$. Then $LTx_n = \langle \xi, Tx_n \rangle = \langle T^\ast \xi, x_n \rangle \to 0$ since $x_n \to 0$ weakly and $\langle T^\ast \xi, \cdot \rangle \in H’$.

You can also directly say $LT$ is continuous since it’s the composition of two continuous functions, namely $L$ and $T$.
